# Why @keyframes animation does not work in Safari inside a link

Tags: safari, css-animations

There is a link inside a block, and the link has an svg that is animated with @keyframes.
I don't know why, but in Safari the animation with @keyframes doesn't work.
In Chrome and other browsers it works fine.

What could be the problem?

Here is the sample html and css structure:

```
<div class="logo-header__new">
  <a href="/">
    <svg width="231" height="40" viewBox="0 0 231 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <!--There is a lot of path inside with 'logo-header__letter-color' class-->
    </svg>
  </a>
</div>

.logo-header__letter-color {
    animation: logo-animation-toscroll 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes logo-animation-toscroll {
    0% {
        fill: #398bea;
    }
    50% {
        fill: #fdc046;
    }
    100% {
        fill: #398bea;
    }
}
```